How to schedule a task that runs once every day only if the user has logged in
When an user logs in to his pc, we need to perform a certain task, but this task should only be done once a day.
So if the user logs in/out several times a day, only the first time the task should start.
If the uses leaves his pc active for more then 24hours, the task should also start each 24hours.
How can we have both conditions met with the windows task scheduler?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@Community seeing the given answer... it is safe to say the question was clear enough. Maybe a word count inside a bot is not the good way to auto spam questions?

I believe the settings highlighted in these two screenshots will do what you want, with the third setting optional depending on what you want.

General Tab > "Run only when user is logged on"
Triggers Tab > New > "Begin the task: On a schedule" > Daily

Maybe depending on your preference:

Settings Tab > "Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed"

If the task/program has a chance of getting stuck, you might want to also look at:

Settings Tab > Dropdown box below "If the task is already running, then the following rule applies"

Beyond all that, just going through the tabs in the "Create Task" window, the settings are pretty self explanatory for how to further customize how the task runs.





Thanks for the details! Will play around with those settings to see what fits our need.
